# __str__ method iterating over class attributes

Tags: python, string, class, attributes

I have a class with attributes made of several lists (today 8 but it'll grow for sure because my code relies on a previous code that is used on prod on another project)

This class has a `__str__` function to pretty print information of the list. Today the function displays information about each list but calling them namely and I don't like that because every time my class attributes changes (add / remove list) I have to update this method

I'm looking for a way to dynamically iterate over my class attributes to display information

As an example, let's imagine the class below

```
class shopping_cart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fruits = []
        self.vegetables = []
        self.meat = []
        self.bread = []

    def __str__(self):
        msg = ""
        msg += "shopping cart content\n"
        msg += "---------------------\n"
        msg += "---fruits-----------: " + len(self.fruits) +"\n
        msg += "---vegetables-------: " + len(self.vegetables) +"\n
        msg += "---meat-------------: " + len(self.meat) +"\n
        msg += "---bread------------: " + len(self.bread) +"\n
        return msg
```

As you can see the maintenance cost is high. I'm looking for something more dynamic, that will look more like

```
class shopping_cart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fruits = []
        self.vegetables = []
        self.meat = []
        self.bread = []

    def __str__(self):
        msg = ""
        msg += "shopping cart content\n"
        msg += "---------------------\n"
        for item in <list of my class attributes>:
            msg += "---" + item +"-----------: " + len(item) +"\n
        return msg
```

Easy to read and easy to maintain.

Comment: In something like your example, I would rather use a dict than a bunch of unrelated attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the one functionality you are looking for is `dir` and `getattr`. Here is the example

```
class shopping_cart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fruits = []
        self.vegetables = []
        self.meat = []
        self.bread = []

    def __str__(self):
        msg = ""
        msg += "shopping cart content\n"
        msg += "---------------------\n"
        members = [attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
        for item in members:
            msg += "---" + item +"-----------: " + str(getattr(self,item) )+"\n"
        return msg
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in a few ways:

1 - use the __dict__ attribute of your class. That gives you a dictionary object of all the variables, and you can iterate through them

```
s = shopping_cart()
s.__dict__
```

that should output something like

```
{'fruits':[], 'vegetables':[], ... }
```

2 - You could use a dictionary of lists, instead of a bunch of lists, and iterate on the dictionary.

3 - You could also use a list of lists (e.g. [self.fruits, self.vegetables...], and iterate on that.

Comment: Thanks Julio, the thing is I need to do it inside the class itself and not on an instance

Comment: You're welcome. Then probably solutions 2 and 3 would work best for you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function on an *instance* of the class (not the `class` itself):

```
class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fruits = []
        self.vegetables = []
        self.meat = []
        self.bread = []

    def __str__(self):
        msg  = "shopping cart contents\n"
        msg += "----------------------\n"
        for attrname in vars(self):
            value = getattr(self, attrname)
            if isinstance(value, list):
                msg += "---{}{}: {:2}\n".format(
                            attrname, '-'*(15-len(attrname)), len(value))
        return msg


cart = ShoppingCart()
print(cart)
```

Output:

```
shopping cart contents
----------------------
---fruits---------:  0
---vegetables-----:  0
---meat-----------:  0
---bread----------:  0
```

Comment: Excellent! this is exactly what I want. thanks a lot